# Regex to replace a string not within quotes (single or double)

Tags: java, regex

I have a input string

> this or "that or" or 'this or that'

that should be translated to

> this || "that or" || "this or that"

So the attempt is to look for an occurence of a string ( or ) within a string and replace it with another string ( || ). I have tried the following code

```
Pattern.compile("( or )(?:('.*?'|\".*?\"|\\S+)\\1.)*?").matcher("this or \"that or\" or 'this or that'").replaceAll(" || ")
```

The output is

> this || "that or" || 'this || that'

The problem being that string within the single quote was also replaced.
As for the code, the style is just for an example. I would compile the pattern and reuse it when I get this to work.

Comment: You need to avoid check in single or double quotes: Try adding [^'] in your regex pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this regex: -

```
"or(?=([^\"']*[\"'][^\"']*[\"'])*[^\"']*$)"
```

It matches `or` which is followed by any characters followed by a certain number of *pairs* of `"` or `'`, followed by a any characters till the end.

```
String str = "this or \"that or\" or 'this or that'";
str = str.replaceAll("or(?=([^\"']*[\"'][^\"']*[\"'])*[^\"']*$)", "||");        
System.out.println(str);
```

**Output : -**

```
this || "that or" || 'this or that'
```

---

The above regex will also replace `or`, if you have a mismatch of `"` and `'`.

For e.g: -

```
"this or \"that or\" or \"this or that'"
```

It will replace `or` for the above strings also. If you want it not to replace in the above case, you can change the regex to: -

```
str = str.replaceAll("or(?=(?:[^\"']*(\"|\')[^\"']*\\1)*[^\"']*$)", "||");
```