# How to create a regex that matches a specific text outside quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I'm looking for some help on creating a regex to replace text in the following format:

```
Replace the 3 words 'OR' and 'AND' and 'NOT' with '||', '&&' and '!' respectively. 
But don't replace it if those 3 words appear somewhere within quotes.
```

For e.g., The sentence

```
PANDA OR THOR AND "NOTHING OR EVERYTHING" NOT THINKING
```

should be changed to

```
PANDA || THOR && "NOTHING OR EVERYTHING" ! THINKING
```

I'm using the Java API String.replaceAll(regex, replacement) to replace the text.

EDIT: I'm not trying to replace them all in a single 'replaceAll' statement. I'll replace them one at a time. But I'm looking for help on the regex to replace them.

Comment: Please, show us your effort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to replace a string not within quotes (single or double)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739866/regex-to-replace-a-string-not-within-quotes-single-or-double)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write three `replaceAll` functions.

```
string.replaceAll("(?m)\\bOR\\b(?=(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*$)", "||")
      .replaceAll("(?m)\\bAND\\b(?=(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*$)", "&&")
      .replaceAll("(?m)\\bNOT\\b(?=(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*$)", "!");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that in one `replaceAll` since you an have only one replacement. Consider using regex which will find quotes or parts you want to replace. Then check if found match is not quote and replace it with what you want (you can use `Matcher` and its `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` methods).

So your code can look like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]+\"|\\bAND\\b|\\bOR\\b|\\bNOT\\b");
//                           "quotes"      AND       OR       NOT
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

StringBuffer sb =new StringBuffer();

while(m.find()){
    String match = m.group();

    if (match.startsWith("\"")){//it is quotation, append it without changes
        m.appendReplacement(sb, match);
    }else if(match.equals("AND")){
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "&&");
    }else //...rest of your cases
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm not trying to replace them all in a single 'replaceAll' statement. I'll replace them one at a time. But I'm looking for help on the regex to replace them.

Comment: @user2869520 it won't be possible with one single regex statement.

Comment: @user2869520: The advantage of this method is that the string is parsed only once.